# Is MySQL Optimizing MyISAM table to MASTER server can also replicate to SLAVE server?

Tags: mysql, database-replication, myisam, master-slave

I have replication setup which is I have MASTER and SLAVE server.
When I optimizing my table to MASTER, is it also replicate to my SLAVE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is answered in the documentation.

`OPTIMIZE TABLE t1` statements will be executed on replicas after the optimize is complete on the master, unless you use one of the following:

```
OPTIMIZE LOCAL TABLE t1
OPTIMIZE NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG TABLE t1
```

The `LOCAL` and `NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG` options are identical.  One is simply an alias for the other, and when either is provided, the `OPTIMIZE` is not replicated.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html